# Voice in one language to another language

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, silverlight, ado.net

I have a requirement which i would like to achieve using .net.What i want is that any person who is having a mic attached should speak in some language.He can select some language from the application and the application would convert his voice into that particular language.i.e Voice-to-Voice conversion. How can i do this?Is there some third party API?How should i start?

Comment: Your question is really broad and not specific enough to answer on SO. Also, I don't see how any of your tags, other than the .NET one, apply to your question.

Answer (score 5):

When you get that one solved, you'll be rich.

Obstacle 1: Voice recognition alone is hard, and nobody has gotten it right yet.  Here's a good starting point for the basis of this statement:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/whatever-happened-to-voice-recognition.html

Obstacle 2: Translation from one language to another is buggy when done by a PC (try Google Translate - translate from English to another language and back to English - it's funny!).

Your question isn't really answerable.... Yet.  The technology isn't there... not even to do a half-baked job of it.  Even though it's not an answer to your question, realistically, if this is a true project, and you don't have unlimited dollars to achieve this, you need to go back to the stakeholders and tell them that the requirement is unreasonable.  Telling your client a requirement is unreasonable or unattainable is something we all have to live with, and it is a valid "resolution" to the problem.